# Pandas: Add rows in the groups of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [1,2,5,6,2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6],
               "variable": ["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D"]})
```

```
   date variable
0   1   A
1   2   A
2   5   A
3   6   A
4   2   B
5   3   B
6   4   B
7   5   B
8   1   C
9   3   C
10  4   C
11  5   C
12  6   C
13  1   D
14  2   D
15  3   D
16  4   D
17  5   D
18  6   D
```

In this data frame, there are 4 values in the `variable` column: A, B, C, D. My goal is that each of the variables needs to contain 1 to 6 dates in the `date` column.

But currently, a few values in the date column are missing for some `variable`. I tried grouping them and filling each value with a counter but sometimes there are more than one dates missing (For example, in `variable` A, the dates 4 and 5 are missing). Also, the counter made my code terribly slow as I have a couple of thousand of rows.

Is there a faster and smarter way to do this without using a counter?

The desired output should be as follows:

```
date    variable
0   1   A
1   2   A
2   3   A
3   4   A
4   5   A
5   6   A
6   1   B
7   2   B
8   3   B
9   4   B
10  5   B
11  6   B
12  1   C
13  2   C
14  3   C
15  4   C
16  5   C
17  6   C
18  1   D
19  2   D
20  3   D
21  4   D
22  5   D
23  6   D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grpupby` + `reindex`

```
df.groupby('variable', as_index=False).apply(
           lambda g: g.set_index('date').reindex([1,2,3,4,5,6]).ffill().bfill())
           .reset_index(level=1)
```

Output:

```
 date   variable
0   1   A
0   2   A
0   3   A
0   4   A
0   5   A
0   6   A
1   1   B
1   2   B
1   3   B
1   4   B
1   5   B
1   6   B
2   1   C
2   2   C
2   3   C
2   4   C
2   5   C
2   6   C
3   1   D
3   2   D
3   3   D
3   4   D
3   5   D
3   6   D
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame([*product(
    range(df.date.min(), df.date.max() + 1),
    sorted({*df.variable})
)], columns=df.columns)

    date variable
0      1        A
1      1        B
2      1        C
3      1        D
4      2        A
5      2        B
6      2        C
7      2        D
8      3        A
9      3        B
10     3        C
11     3        D
12     4        A
13     4        B
14     4        C
15     4        D
16     5        A
17     5        B
18     5        C
19     5        D
20     6        A
21     6        B
22     6        C
23     6        D
```

Comment: That's a brilliant way of doing it! IIUC, you are creating a new data frame which has ```date``` from 1 to 6 for each ```variable```. But what if I have more columns in my data frame which I want to keep intact (For example, variable A has a date 1 which has the value 1.22 in some ```X``` column. Now when I add the missing date 3 to the variable, can I add a np.nan in the corresponding column ```X```?) Can you help me achieve this too?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: ```ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns```

Comment: @PratyushaPasumarty I’d ask a new question. This one helped unlock a certain level of understanding. Use that understanding to ask another question (-:

Comment: @harvpan answer solved that issue. But thanks for such a quick response! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a work around but it should work

```
df.groupby(by=['variable']).agg({'date': range(6)}).explode('date')
```

Comment: *explode* is a function introduced in version *0.25.0*. You probably have some older version of *Pandas*.